# How to pass a hex color as argument to a new command?

Tags: color

I would like to pass a color in HEX format to my `arr` command. I do not want to define a color.

```
\newcommand{\arr}[2]{
    {\tikz{\path[draw=#1,line width=1.5mm, line join=round,line cap=round, -
{Straight Barb[scale=0.8, line join=round,line cap=round]}, 
rotate=#2-45,scale = 0.8] (0,0) -- (0.9,0.9);}}
}
\arr{326EC8}{90}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way would be to define the color within the `arr` macro:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\arr}[2]{%
    \definecolor{myColor}{HTML}{#1}%
    \tikz{%
        \path[
            draw=myColor,
            line width=1.5mm, 
            line join=round,
            line cap=round, 
            ->, 
            rotate=#2-45,
            scale = 0.8,
        ] 
        (0,0) -- (0.9,0.9);
    }%
}

\begin{document}
    \arr{326EC8}{90}%
    \arr{232F3E}{45}%
\end{document}
```